# django error: Exception Value: 'FieldFile' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

I am using django version 1.5c1 on Mac OS X 10.8.2 and Python 2.7.2

I have the following model defined in the `model.py` file:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to = '%Y/%m/%d')
```

and registered this to the automatic admin interface by adding the following lines to the `admin.py` file:

```
class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('filename',)
    fields = ('filename',)

admin.site.register(MyFile, FileAdmin)
```

When adding a new `File` object to the database using the admin webinterface, I always get the following error message:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mytest/myfile/add/

Django Version: 1.5c1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'registry',
 'mytest')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  208.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1009.                 self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  530.             action_flag     = ADDITION
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py" in log_action
  18.         e = self.model(None, None, user_id, content_type_id,   smart_text(object_id), object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/mytest/myfile/add/
Exception Value: 'FieldFile' object is not subscriptable
```

The file is saved in the correct location but nothing gets added in the database. Any clues on how to interpret this `'FieldFile' object is not subscriptable` error message?

Kind regards,
Hans

Comment: Rename "model.py" to "models.py" and try again and then test which models are shown at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/. Don't forget to run 'syncdb'.

Comment: Sorry, my typo: model.py was indeed models.py... The MyFile model is shown at 127.0.0.1:8000/admin... Syncdb was also run and inspection of the postgres database indeed shows that the mytest_myfile has been created correctly. Any hints?

Comment: @user1974144, this is probably a django 1.5 bug based on the fact there are no references to it on google, and your use case is *extremely simple* and would be everywhere should it be a consistent error. Remember, django 1.5 is the development branch. Don't use it unless you're developing it... you will regret it later. I spent hours tracking down a bug where request.GET shared state between requests.. guess why? Dev branch. It's not production ready.

Comment: Indeed, this is a 1.5 bug! Going back to 1.4 solved the problem! Thank you.